# Need a WYSIWYG plugin

Tags: 6, nodes, wysiwyg

Straight to the point, I need a WYSIWYG module for Drupal 6; here are the requirements:

- Easy to change the toolbar button
- Able to add custom style
- Able to upload image and put into content
- Able to upload flash and render it inside content
- Able to upload file and show it as download link inside content

Anybody familiar with Wordpress WYSIWYG editor? That is something like what I want.

Comment: if you Google "Drupal WYSIWYG" you're 90% there.

Comment: Hi, wrburgess

Just let u know, I been researching a lot in Google and Drupal plugin pages. I know there are lot of plugins offer those functionality that I want but I would like to know other people opinions about this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to use [WYSIWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) you should consider using [WYSIWYG Filter](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_filter) to ensure that users do not include markup that you do not want to get through. Without the filter and full html text format enabled users can switch from full html or which other formats you have defined to plain text where they can add whatever markup they want and back to full html to by pass the plain text filter. With WYSIWYG filter you can ensure that bad markup or even corrupt js does not make it through the WYSIWYG editor.

Another way to ensure clean markup is to create your own text format and only enabling the WYSIWYG editors buttons that produce the same markup that you allow through your format.

[elFinder](http://drupal.org/project/elfinder) is probably the best file manager out there at the moment. I find it's UI is much better than [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce)

Comment: i like ur elFinder suggestion! trying to install CKFinder really pain in the butt.. Now, how do u do embbed media? I found most of the modules are for D6... Sad

Comment: i mark urs is the answer since i like ur elFinder suggestion!

Comment: I haven't used elfinder with FCKeditor but it probably works the same as TinyMCE. Once the module is installed you'll need to enable elFinder in the Buttons and Plugins settings for your WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [WYSIWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module...  TinyMCE allows for media to be added such as Flash, so you can use that plugin.

For files/images you can use the [Insert module](http://drupal.org/project/insert) **OR** [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) (along with [IMCE Wysiwyg API Bridge](http://drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg)) to add the images/files to the content.

Remember Google can be a wonderful thing ;)

Comment: I understand about how to upload files but how to render Flash inside the textarea?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [WYSIWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) with whichever Javascript WYSIWYG library you want to use, you'll probably also want [Linkit](http://drupal.org/project/linkit), [Image Browser](http://drupal.org/project/imagebrowser), etc., etc.

You should probably also make sure that you've got a good HTML cleanup configuration in your input formats and that your WYSIWYG configuration will only generate tags that other filters aren't going to strip out again. You'll also want to make sure that pasting "rich text" from other applications into your WYSIWYG will be treated correctly (cleaning up the junk from Word, normalising `style="font-weight:bold"` to `<strong>`, etc.)

Making a useful, reliable, "correct" WYSIWYG configuration requires more than just installing the modules.

Comment: Linkit plugin is good! Thanks for sharing that. do you know any module that has embbed media support?

Comment: @Roberto I'm not sure about Drupal 6, but [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) is going to rock for Drupal 7 sites.

Comment: is it safe to use this module? since it is still on beta version.

Comment: @Roberto If you need to ask the question, probably not. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I use WYSIWYG, CKEditor, IMCE, and the IMCE WYSIWYG Bridge.  You can configure profiles that you assign to roles for various things like HTML filters, confine the user to an upload directory based on their UID (sites/default/files/%uid), and just a lot of other really awesome stuff.

Here is the guide that I found that finally put all of this together for me:

http://himerus.com/blog/himerus/inline-images-drupal-wysiwyg-api-tinymce-and-imce

Comment: hi, thanks for responding my question, sorry.. I will skip IMCE.. It has really basic uploading features, try elFinder, it is cool! All you need just drop the files and install module, it works like charms!